# How to print date time in acumatica report?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to print date and time of the printing  at the footer section of acumatica report.

I can print date using `Now()`, but it is not printing the time. Is there any way I can get the time part along with date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Now function only prints the date part and not date time. I have used Format function to print Date & time in the report

=Format( '{0:G}', Now() )

Answer (score 0):

Use the Now() function inside the page header.  Review screen ID AR650500.  That has a proper example you can use.